# Bound the rank of $u\otimes A\in\mathbb R\otimes\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n$ by the rank of $A$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let $l,m,n\in\mathbb N$, $u\in\mathbb R$, $A\in\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n$ and $B:=u\otimes A\in\mathbb R\otimes\mathbb R^m\otimes\mathbb R^n$. I want to show a hilariously simple thing: Assuming the rank of the matrix$^1$ $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ is at most a prescribed $r\in\mathbb N$, then the rank of the matrix $B\in\mathbb R^{(1\times m)\times n}$ is at most $r$ as well.

> How can we do that?

It's hard for me to not getting confused by the involved reindexing. Can we express the range of $B$ in terms of the range of $A$?

---

$^1$ Remember that if $H_i$ is a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space with $d_i:=\dim H_i\in\mathbb N$, we have canonically isomorphisms $$H_1\otimes H_2\cong\mathfrak L(H_1,H_2)\cong\left(\mathbb R^{d_2}\right)^{d_1}\cong\mathbb R^{d_1\times d_2}\tag1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have for general linear operators $T_i \in \mathrm{Hom}(V_i,W_i)$ that
$$\mathrm{rank} \left(\otimes_{i=1}^n T_i\right) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathrm{rank}(T_i).$$

This can for example be found in the lecture notes by [Tin-Yau Tam](http://webhome.auburn.edu/~tamtiny/math7970-11f.html) (theorem 3.4.2).

Thinking of $u$ as a $1 \times 1$ matrix yields your bound.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While it's pretty clear to me that the rank-formula should hold, I'm struggling to see how the proof can be performed without too much notational complexity. Since the proof in your reference is not clear to me (and there are some typos), I've asked a separate question for that: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3619386/47771